# How can I verify If Keyboard is open or not in Appium using Ruby

Tags: ruby, appium

I am trying to verify that, if keyboard is open or not.
To hide the keyboard we have:  hide_keyboard
but I did not get anything to check if keyboard is open or not in Appium using Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose, `$driver` is your `Appium::Driver` instance:

```
def keyboard_present?
  if $driver.device_is_android?
    `adb shell dumpsys input_method`[/mInputShown=\w+/i].split('=')[1] == 'true'
  else
    begin
      # $driver.driver will return Selenium::WebDriver instance
      # we set implicit wait to 0.1 to get immediate response 
      $driver.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 0.1
      # make sure to reset implicit wait back to default (20, I guess), if needed
      $driver.find_element(:xpath, '//UIAKeyboard').displayed?
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
      false
    end
  end
end
```