# Test if software keyboard is opened

Tags: selenium, testing, mobile

I have a specific question. I saw it here few time but only according to appium.
Is there any option to check if SW keyboard on mobile is opened , when I am using selenium and run tests on computer ? I mean without appium.

Thanks

Comment: As I understand, So you are not testing mobile application, you are testing mobile web site, am I right?

Comment: Yes exactly, it is a mobile web page.

Comment: There is no method in selenium for detecting mobile keyboard because it is out of level which selenium is applicable. Selenium drivers only able to run on browser level, not on the mobile os level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check If Keyboard is open or not in Appium using JAVA and ADB command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582183/how-can-i-check-if-keyboard-is-open-or-not-in-appium-using-java-and-adb-command)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I verify If Keyboard is open or not in Appium using Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034590/how-can-i-verify-if-keyboard-is-open-or-not-in-appium-using-ruby)

Comment: What language are you using?  I've found solutions for this in Java (see @natn2323 comment above) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034590/how-can-i-verify-if-keyboard-is-open-or-not-in-appium-using-ruby) in Ruby.

Comment: After few hours of research we decided to use appium, it should be the easiest way.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, appium as the testing tool but what programming language to write the scripts?

Comment: I need to use kotlin.

Comment: You can answer your own question and also accept it for future visitor to validate solution. @eMZet